# Cannot find JUnit and Robolectric using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to create a simple unit test project using JUnit and Robolectric. The build.gradle file is attached below.

```
evaluationDependsOn(':blitzen')

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    def blitzenModule = project(':blitzen')
    compile blitzenModule

    testCompile blitzenModule.android.applicationVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
    testCompile blitzenModule.android.applicationVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.outputs.files
    testCompile files(blitzenModule.plugins.findPlugin("com.android.application").getBootClasspath())

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
}
```

Where "blitzen" is the app this test project is testing. Gradle was able to download junit and robolectric. However, I still got compiler errors on test code which complains about not being able to find various junit and robolectric packages. Do I need to add anything else in the build script so that the junit and robolectric jars can be used correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have put the test code inside "src/main/..." instead of "src/test/...". Relocating the test source files resolves the issue.